# How can I get value of a shell environment in a tmux pane?

Tags: tmux

Does `tmux` support a way to get the value of an environment variable for a shell running inside of it?

For example, I'd like to get the value of `$PATH` in each pane.

Comment: [Not a trivial task](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29128/108618). I don't expect `tmux` to even try.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe there could be a workaround, something like sending in `echo $PATH` and accessing its response somehow?

Comment: This assumes the shell is not busy. Why do you need `tmux` to know `$PATH` of another process? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: I'd like to use `tmux-resurrect` hooks to save some specific environment variables. Requiring that the shell isn't busy when saving its environment would be an alright compromise.

Comment: You will need to do it from your shell, there is no practical way to make tmux retrieve environment variables from other processes. You could save them into a file or use a tmux user option or whatever you prefer. If it is only a couple you could just add something like `[ -n "$TMUX" ] && echo $PATH >$HOME/.saved-variables/$TMUX_PANE` to your PS1.

Answer (score 1):

Use
`tmux send-keys 'echo $PATH > /tmp/path.txt'`

Then read the `/tmp/path.txt` in your script